# Schema option in spark_read_parquet()

Tags: apache-spark-sql, sparkr, sparklyr

I am pretty new to R and spark. I want to read a parquet file with the following code. Anyone knows how to specify schema there?

```
 library(sparklyr)

 sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn",
                     appname = "test") 

 df <- spark_read_parquet(sc,
                     "name",
                     "path/to/the/file",
                      repartition = 0,
                      schema = "?")
```

I looked at the link https://spark.rstudio.com/reference/spark_read_parquet/, there isn't any detail or example regarding how to set schema in the function to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to read a parquet file, a schema does not need to be used, it is just an available option. The following code should work.

```
df <- spark_read_parquet(sc,
                 "name",
                 "path/to/the/file",
                  repartition = 0,
                  schema = Null)
```

But if you want to use a schema, there are many options and choosing the right one depends on your data and what you are using it for. But try running your code without a schema option to see if that works for your data.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
tbl_change_db(sc, "dbName")
```

and if u are using RStudio then click the refresh button on the upper right part of snippet